# How can I reference to an element on an ArrayList of objects. to invoke some method on that object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, reference

How can I reference an element on an `ArrayList` of objects to invoke some method on that object.

For example:

```
//antsNumber is number entered by the user
Ants antsArray[];
antsArray=new Ants[antsNumber];
```

Inside `Ants` object there are some methods.  I want to do something like this if possible..

```
for(int count=0;count<ants.size();count++){
   ants.elementAt(count).plaplapla;
}
```

I tried to use foreach:

```
for(Ants ant:antsArray){
```

But it didn't work because I need to know which is the number of element in this array so I can send it to other method to access it easily.

Comment: `new Ants[antsNumber]` that's not an arraylist

Comment: Your words say "array list", but your code keeps saying "array".

Comment: What do you mean by *...know which is the number of element in this array* ? In the example code, you don't really care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ants[count]` will reference a single element of the array (that's not an ArrayList).

If it was an ArrayList then the syntax would be `ants.get(count)`  instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just get each element from the array with for each loop and then call the method;

```
for(Ants ant:antsArray){
    ant.someMethod();
}
```

or:

```
for(int i=0; i < antsArray.length; i++){
    antsArray[i].someMethod();
}
```

Both of this code will allow you to call the method on all of the objects.

NOTE:
An array is not equivalent to ArrayList